# How to navigate to a new page using button click in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've not worked on angularJS. I'm trying to navigate to a different page using button onclick functionality.

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
   <p>
      Start editing to see some magic happen :)
   </p>
   <body ng-app="myapp">
      <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
         <button ng-click="clicked()">Click</button> 
      </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>  
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS code

```
var VLogin = angular.module('myapp',[]);
VLogin.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.clicked = function(){   
window.location = "#/index.html";            
};
});
```

Comment: Don't do this. Use routing - [Angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) is an excellent alternative to the default routing - remember, AngularJS is a SPA framework so you shouldn't be trying to navigate around to .html pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.clicked = function(){   
    window.location.href = "#/index.html";            
};
```